# How to put Cherrypy wsgi behind Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, cherrypy

I was following by [lalalalalalalambda example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844182/getting-started-with-cherrypy-and-jinja2) to put cherrypy behind nginx server, but didn't acomplish anything except *nginx 502 bad gataway* at my home Debian distro. 
Here is Nginx settings :

```
location / {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Ofcourse there is IP instead of socket, but tried hard to make it work by following numerious of examples over the net.
I'm hosting several domains with static html in production server, and trying to switch to python. I hope if I solve this issue, I will deploy my python app without any pain.

Comment: Are you able to view the website when you go to the IP specified for uwsgi_pass?

Comment: Yes, directly on localhost:8080 it works beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using uwsgi to run my cherrypy websites behind nginx and i'm using the following location config settings...

```
    location / {
     proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
     proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    X-Originating-IP    $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR    $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header    CLIENT_IP           $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080/;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is your server_name set to?

Comment: In the first line of question is link to exact example in Cherrypy by lalalalalalalambda user. Please take a look...dunno is the server_name mandatory...bit confused.

Comment: Yes...I was working around and it started successfully. Thanx huge.